# How to sign-in an application using Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Is Generate Signed APK wizard enough for obtaining a signed-in application in Android Studio? Does it actually use keytool and jarsigner tools?

Comment: I've signed mine using that. Select your signer file and then insert your password and you'll have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,it is.

You can use signature in android studio, or other tools like keytool, jarsigner tools it makes no difference. 
As far as i remember android generates 2 versions of you apk on default (signed and not signed).